# Twitter OAuth connects via localhost, fails on live version?

Tags: php, twitter

It seems to be a problem with `redirect.php` not grabbing the access token properly. I've browsed around and found that lots of people have this problem but I can't figure out how to resolve it. This same code works on localhost but fails on my live version. Any ideas why/how to fix it? Is there a way I can manually set these?

```
<?php

/* Start session and load library. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

/* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

/* Get temporary credentials. */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

/* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:
    /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
    $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
    header('Location: ' . $url); 
    break;
  default:
    /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a different library? I've had no problems with the EpiTwitter one http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-async-documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

Verify callback URL in http://dev.twitter.com/apps/
it might be pointing to the `redirect.php` on wrong server.